# Tailwind CSS: How to use custom percentages in padding?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How can we use custom percentage on padding in Tailwind CSS?

My config:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '80\%': '80%', // p-80% - doesn't work
      }
    },
  },
```

We can achieve that in the old way with the plain CSS:

```
.p-80\% {
   padding: 80%;
}
```

But ideally, we can do it with Tailwind too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 42):

While the other answers do provide an answer, this can be frustrating if you only need to use the custom value once. I found this answer when trying to solve such an issue, so for those who find this after me, tailwind now supports [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding#arbitrary-values).

You can use them by appending square brackets containing a CSS value (e.g. `[80%]`) to a prefix such as `p-` for padding or `mr-` for margin-right.

```html
<div class="p-[80%]">
    Hello world!
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to escape the percent sign for Tailwind, it will take care of that. Here's a play example https://play.tailwindcss.com/CYR6JOXYyz?file=config

```
theme: {
  extend: {
    spacing: {
      '80%': '80%', // p-80% - should work
    }
  },
},
```

The class Tailwind will create is `.p-80\%` for the above config.

Answer (score 2):

I found that using spacing to customize more than padding, *margin, width, and height* [all at once](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding#padding-scale)

Code

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
     extend: {
      padding: {
        'p-80': '80%',
      },
      // Build your palette here
          colors: {
      'black': '#393939',
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Markup

```html
<a href="#" class="p-80">TailWindCSS Dev</a>
```